# How to stop JavaScript interval after on full run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WEYKL/1098/). How can I stop the animation and interval after reaching `100%` and filling the progress bar?

I tried adding `clearInterval(myVar);` to the end of interval but this stops incrementing the percentage text

```
$(".progress-bar").animate({
    width: "100%"
}, 3000);
```

Code:

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1);
var count = 0;
function myTimer() {
if(count < 100){
  $('.progress').css('width', count + "%");
  count += 0.05;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.round(count) +"%";
   // code to do when loading
  }
  
  else if(count > 99){  
      // code to do after loading
  count = 0;
  }
}
clearInterval(myVar);
```

Comment: Did you mean to put the `clearInterval` call at the line where you put the comment `// code to do after loading`?  Where you've placed it, it runs before the first iteration of the `setInterval` function is even queued...

Comment: You should be able to add the ```clearInterval(myVar)``` to the ```else if(count > 99)``` statement.  I tried it on your jsfiddle and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a timer for this. jQuery provides a way for you to listen to the progress of the animation:

```
$(".progress-bar").animate({
    width: "100%"
},{
    duration: 3000,
    progress: function(_, progr) {
        $('#demo').text( Math.round(100 * progr));          
    }
});
```

See your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WEYKL/1101/)

NB: I changed your `demo` element to a `span`, as a `p` will break the `%` to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the code of clearing the interval in the block where you handle the finishing of loading.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    myTimer()
}, 1);
var count = 0;

function myTimer() {
    if (count < 100) {
        $('.progress').css('width', count + "%");
        count += 0.05;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.round(count) + "%";
        // code to do when loading
    } else if (count > 99) {
        // code to do after loading
        count = 0;
        // loading is done, clear the interval
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
}
```